# Convert text dates to dates and then keeping the NA values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe containing a dates field as text.

I convert the dates field into a date time object using:

> df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

Doing:

> df['date']

Produces something like this:

```
0    2012-06-28 09:36:21
1    2013-05-21 14:52:57
2    2011-10-14 16:31:34
3    2011-11-11 12:51:13
4    2013-02-07 15:33:22
5    2013-01-02 14:40:08
6    2013-06-24 14:49:40
7    2013-07-15 15:29:26
8    2011-11-04 12:17:32
9    2013-04-29 17:31:43
10   2013-06-24 15:00:06
11   2012-10-22 18:23:53
12                   NaT
13                   NaT
14   2011-12-13 10:06:18
```

Now I convert the date time object into a date object:

> df['date'].apply(try_convert_date)

(see below for how try_to_convert is defined). I get:

```
0       2012-06-28
1       2013-05-21
2       2011-10-14
3       2011-11-11
4       2013-02-07
5       2013-01-02
6       2013-06-24
7       2013-07-15
8       2011-11-04
9       2013-04-29
10      2013-06-24
11      2012-10-22
12    0001-255-255
13    0001-255-255
14      2011-12-13
```

Where the 'NaT' values have been converted to '0001-255-255'. How do I avoid this and keep 'NA' in these cells?

Thanks in advance

```
def try_convert_date(obj):

    try:
        return obj.date()
    except: #AttributeError:
        return 'NA'
```

Comment: keep in mind that in pandas itself this will not be useful (e.g. ``date`` is not a supported dtype). What are you going to do with this?

Comment: see https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/9513

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `pd.NaT.date()` will not raise an error, it will return `datetime.date(1, 255, 255)`, so the part of your code where you catch an exception will never be reached. You'll have to check if the value is `pd.NaT` and in that case return 'NA'. In all other cases you can safely return `obj.date()` since the column has `datetime64` dtype.

```
def try_convert(obj):
    if obj is pd.NaT:
        return 'NA'
    else:
        return obj.date()

n [17]: s.apply(try_convert)
Out[17]:
0     2012-06-28
1     2013-05-21
2     2011-10-14
3     2011-11-11
4     2013-02-07
5     2013-01-02
6     2013-06-24
7     2013-07-15
8     2011-11-04
9     2013-04-29
10    2013-06-24
11    2012-10-22
12            NA
13            NA
14    2011-12-13
Name: 1_2, dtype: object
```